# Subplot and hlines in matplotlib does not work together

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to plot several plots via subplot and also plotting hlines on plot, but the moment I switch on the subplot section, the hlines disappear and come back after switching off subplot option. Could someone help how could one have both active?

```
## TSH | Time Series plot
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
#ax = plt.gca()

### Threshold value on Medicine
tshLLimit=0.27
tshHLimit=4.20
ferrLLimit=13.0
ferrHLimit=150.0

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (30,15)
plt.rcParams['font.size']=22

subplot=5
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
fntSize=18

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['TSH1 (muIU/mg)'], color='blue', marker="s")
plt.title('TSH variation')

#plt.yticks(np.arange(0, 8, step=2))
plt.ylim(0)
plt.ylabel('TSH1 (muIU/mg)')
plt.grid(True)
ax.hlines(y=tshLLimit, xmin="02.02.2014", xmax="10.08.2018",linewidth=2, color='red')
ax.hlines(y=tshHLimit, xmin="02.02.2014", xmax="10.10.2018",linewidth=2, color='red')
plt.text("01.01.2014",3,"hairfall", {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': fntSize})
plt.text("02.7.2015",3,"hairfall", {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': fntSize})
plt.text("02.10.2016",3,"hairfall", {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': fntSize})
plt.text("02.06.2018",3,"hairfall", {'color': 'r', 'fontsize': fntSize})


plt.show()
```

Comment: You haven't defined the data frame df in your code so it's hard to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to know exactly what output you're expecting without knowing what your data looks like, but you could try changing

```
plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

to

```
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
```

or call `plt.hlines` rather than `ax.hlines`.

I think this will solve your problem as you're currently adding the hlines to the default axes generated by `plt.subplots()` and not the axes of your subplot.